# Detail missing in exercise on factor groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The goal is to compute the factor group of $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6/\langle(2,3)\rangle$. Now, $H=\langle(2,3)\rangle$ has order $2$ and thus the factor group must have $12$ elements, and since $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ is abelian the factor group must be abelian. Furthermore, the only possible abelian groups of order $12$ are $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$. Up to here everything is clear. It is also clear that $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$  has an element of order $4$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ does not. Why based the order of these couple of groups I can decide that $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_6/\langle(2,3)\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_3$, and not the other one?

EDIT:

While this questions has been marked as duplicate, the original link does answer all of points asked from the same exercise, and therefore THIS IS NOT a duplicate. Consider reading the question and the answer, you may have the same as this, or both of them.

Comment: Or in other words, why do I need to consider the order of $(1,0)+H$ and not just make the observation that a member of $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ is of the form $(a,b,c)$ and therefore for any order $n$ of, say $(x,y,z)^n$, $(x,y,z)^n+H\subseteq H$ is never fulfilled?

Comment: You seem close to finding a proof.  Have you tried to choose an element of order $4$ in the quotient group?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The guy asks three things and I am asking for the third one. The guy who answers says that he should ask separately each question and he answers only the first one. Thus my question is valid.

Comment: @hardmath this is were I am lost. $(1,0)+H$ has order $4$, and there is not an element in $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ that has order $4$, but why the order is so important?

Comment: Okay, we cannot say that a group whose elements can be represented as triples isn't isomorphic to a direct sum of two groups.  I'm sure you can think of a case where just such an isomorphism exists by FTAG.

Comment: Your question is answered in the text of the duplicate question already. No need to look at the answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  I think the OP was curious about a subtle point, as explained in the Comments:  Why do we need to consider the presence of an element of order $4$, if a simpler argument is available?  See my exchange of comments above and the answer posted below.

Comment: @hardmath I see. Your answer is nice, but probably also not new here on  MSE. Of course, one can explain for each duplicate new aspects, but I think this will be too much repetition after all. So for me this is a duplicate.

Comment: An exercise may have many points to be answered, and each user answer either all of them, or just SOME of them. To have the basis the same question but with different points to be addressed IS NOT REPETITION. Don't be stubborn.

Comment: Hi @user2820579 I am not sure what is confusing you here. The order of an element is an invariant that is preserved by isomorphisms. The elements themselves, obviously, aren't. $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_3$ is made up of triplets, but it could(?) (or not?) be isomorphic to the group $\frac{\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_6}{\langle(2,3)\rangle}$ made up of different "stuff" (cosets): it does not matter, as long as there is an isomorphism (a map that preserves all the operations). *That* is why we look at invariants: if they are not preserved, an isomorphism cannot exist.

Comment: Using invariants such as the element order is really a shortcut, but a very useful one: imagine if you had to check all $12^{12}$ maps from $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3$ into $\frac{\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_6}{\langle(2,3)\rangle}$ and verify that none of them was an isomorphism. A Herculean (Sisyphus?) task.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. I get now the idea!

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_6$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$.

So we cannot insist on two groups being non-isomorphic just because one is a direct sum of two factors and the other a direct sum of three factors.

There is something valuable in your intuition about the non-isomorphism of groups expressed as direct products of finite abelian groups, and this is precisely formulated in [the Fundamental Thm. of Finite Abelian Groups](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fundamental_Theorem_of_Finite_Abelian_Groups).

> **Thm.** Every finite abelian group is an internal group direct product of cyclic groups whose orders are prime powers.  The number of terms in the product and the orders of the cyclic groups are uniquely determined by the group.

Thus where a direct product representing finite abelian group has only *prime power order* factors, the number of factors is unique (and can thus serve to show two groups non-isomorphic when the number of factors in two such representations differ).

More generally when a group has a [composition series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series), the number of terms in such series and the (multiplicities of) quotient groups (up to reordering) are unique (and can thus be used to prove non-isomorphism of two groups whose composition series cannot be reconciled).